# How do I set up VSCode to follow the "rules" set by Style CI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, styleci

I'm annoyed by my lack of consistency with the formatting of my code.

I've started using Style CI. More specifically I'm using their Laravel PHP preset which has a [long list of rules](https://docs.styleci.io/presets#laravel).

[image: Excerpt of the rule set]

I'm not sure which type of linter/extension I should be using to bring my editor in line with these same rules. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found "PHP CS Fixer" and "PHP Mess Detector" extensions to be quite good generally for this sort of thing.

PHP CS Fixer is created by sensiolabs and works well in my experience, particularly with Symfony 3 and 4 projects, so should be good with laravel.  It's very configurable, so should be ok to set any of the Style CI bits that are not set like that by default.  I just set PHP CS Fixer to run on save, then you can just fix stuff while you're there.

PHP CS Fixer - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=makao.phpcsfixer

PHP Mess Detector - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecodes.vscode-phpmd